# Determining if a call is on hold

Tags: sip, asterisk, pbx

Is there a way (either in the dialplan, or through some AMI action) to determine whether or not a channel is on hold?

`ChanIsAvail(<some channel ID>)` can be used, but there is not "on hold" status.  Calls on hold have a status of `AST_STATE_UP`.

Answer (score 1):

No,there are no way.

But you can setup event listener via AMI and use it to save such state somewhere(database).

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+manager+events

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Asterisk func device_State

> DEVICE_STATE(device) The possible values for both uses of this
>   function are: UNKNOWN | NOT_INUSE | INUSE | BUSY | INVALID |
>   UNAVAILABLE | RINGING | RINGINUSE | ONHOLD

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+device_State

IF your can extract the device name from the channel (should be do-able), you could then check the status of the associated device.

Hopefully this helps.  If not, if you can give a bit more info on your use-case, I might be able to come up with a different solution.

Comment: I'm using Asterisk 1.8...is there some other module or something I might need to load?